# Boolean function always returning true

Tags: c++, boolean

I am taking a course on Udemy to learn C++, and I am following along with the professor.

This is the exact code that is being used in the class. 
You pass in a letter, and it tells you whether or not it is a vowel. However, it is saying every letter is a vowel. For example, when I pass in 'b', it says it is a vowel.

Any clue?

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

bool isVowel(char letter) {
    if ((letter == 'a') || (letter == 'e') || (letter = 'i') || 
       (letter = 'o') || (letter = 'u'))
    return true;
else
    return false;
}

int main() {

    char let;
    cout << "Enter a letter: ";
    cin >> let;

    if (isVowel(let))
        cout << let << " is a vowel." << endl;
    else
        cout << let << " is a consonant." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

---

I get the same problem using both codeblocks and xcode.

Thanks

Comment: You are using the assignment operator instead of the equality comparison one. Takes 2 seconds to spot.

Comment: Woah, thanks. That is embarrasing.

Comment: And your compiler should spot it for you, if you enable any warnings whatsoever, which you should do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the problem:

(letter = 'i') || (letter = 'o') || (letter = 'u'))

You should change it with the == in order to make the comparison. = is for assignation.

Comment: Thank you, I don't know how I didn't see it.

Comment: It may happen. If it has been useful for you, consider marking my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a character to the variable `letter`, instead of comparing the variable and the character.

A good thing to notice is that the result of an assignation is always true if the assignation was succesful, false if the assignation was not succesful. That means in your code there are at least 3 "true" booleans: `(letter = 'i')`, `(letter = 'o')`, `(letter = 'u')`. These assignations were succesful, so in your `if` statement, they correspond to the boolean `true`.